# Passing video frames for OpenCV-Python while streaming using WebRTC and UV4L driver

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, webrtc, uv4l

I have a raspberry pi setup with the uv4l driver and the native uv4l-WebRTC module. So far, I can see the video stream work fine on my browser, but what I want to do now is to be able to simultaneously stream the video to the browser and also pass some of the frames to my opencv-python program.

I was able to test if I can get some data on a video by using the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

imageMat = np.array((3,4,3), np.uint8)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open('https://<IP ADDRESS:8080>/stream/video.mjpeg')
cap.read(imageMat)
```

which works if I put the URL in the sample code above on my browser. This URL is provided by the people who made the uv4l driver, but the problem is that I actually want to be able to use my custom webpage's video instead of the one being streamed from this default URL.

I've seen from other posts that I can pass the frames by drawing them on a 
canvas element and then turning this into a Blob and then sending it over a websocket, but this would mean that I have to open another websocket (using python this time) but I'm not too sure if this is the correct approach. I thought that by using UV4L, I can easily obtain the frames while still be able to stream the video.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm really in need of a solution for this.

Comment: i'm looking for something similar :D